# std::string with stateful Allocator

Tags: c++, stdstring, allocator

I have a allocator which allocates memory based on its instance variable `MemoryContext`. I tried to create a `std::string` for this kind of allocator. Header looks like this

```
class String {
private:
    std::basic_string< char
                        , std::char_traits<char>
                        , MemoryContextAllocator<char> >  my_string;

public:
    explicit String( MemoryContext* memoryContext );
    ~String();
    MemoryContextAllocator<char> getAllocator() const;

};
```

Source looks like this

```
String::String(MemoryContext* memoryContext)
:my_string( MemoryContextAllocator<char>(memoryContext) )
{
}

String::~String() {
}
```

During compilation, i get an error  like this

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:156:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘`MemoryContextAllocator<char>::MemoryContextAllocator()`’

It is trying to call the constructor of the allocator with no arguments. If i don't want to introduce this default constructor and use setters, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: C++03 requires allocators to be DefaultConstructible, and GCC's `std::string` hasn't been updated to the C++11 allocator requirements yet. You could try using `std::vector<char, MemoryContextAllocator<char>>` instead